# Both way scrollable gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

Is it possible to allow a griview to scroll both vertically and horizontally simultaneously in android? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It doubt that would be possible. A GridView is based on an ArrayAdapter, having only 1 dimension for the items. How would you arrange them in a view that can be extended both vertically and horizontally?

Of course, if you just want to make it larger than the screen and use hard-coded number of rows/columns, you can put it in another scrollable view.

Comment: Is it possible to use a GestureDetector on a gridview to check for gestures and allow scrolling? I observed that there are a few games which allow both way scrolling on a grid. Any idea how this can be achieved. For e.g. I see numerous minesweeper apps on Market which do so. Any help is greatly appreciated. User should be able to scroll the gridview in the direction they want to scroll by sliding their finger across the screen

Comment: I think those games use something other than GridView. You can write a custom UI Widget (extending from the base View class) that draws the 2D grid, and react to touch gestures in a way that 2D scrolling is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are following two solutions and you can use one which fits your requirement.

1. You can use RecyclerView instead of GridView with a custom layout manager. You can read [this](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java) code for help. Also, you can read [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/) article on how to create custom layout manager. This article gives an example of how to create two-way scrolling grid layout.
2. The other solution is to use RecyclerView with horizontal scrolling Grid Layout wrapped inside a scroll view.

   ```
   <ScrollView>
       <RecyclerView />
   </ScrollView>
   ```

   use GridLayoutManager with horizontal scroll for recycler view.

The first solution is efficient in a way that it handles view recycling properly.

Hope this will help.